# Chunks size or timeout asyncio python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to unstack a queue by getting chunks of it specifying a **chunk_size** and a **timeout**.

For instance, I want the `get_chunks` function to return either a list of **chunk_size** items if it takes less than **timeout** to get them otherwise a list of length between 9 and **chunk_size**.

Here is the code so far:

```
import asyncio

async def populate(queue):
    for i in range(0, 100):
        await queue.put(i)

async def _get_chunks(queue, chunk_size):
    items = []
    for i in range(0, chunk_size):
        items.append(await queue.get())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    return items

async def get_chunks(queue, chunk_size, timeout):
    while True:
        yield _get_chunks(queue, chunk_size)

async def listen():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await populate(queue)
    print(f'{queue.qsize()} items in queue')
    async for chunk in get_chunks(queue, 10, 1):
        print(await chunk)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(listen())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think there is a way to do it using `asyncio.wait` such that:

```
done, not_done = asyncio.wait([_get_chunks(queue, size),
                               asyncio.sleep(timeout)],
                              return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETE)
items = done.pop().result()
```

but i cannot manage to get the result when `asyncio.sleep` returns first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the result because `_get_chunks` is not yet finished. A simple workaround is to have some shared state between `_get_chunks` and its caller:

```
async def _get_chunks(queue, chunk_size, out):
    for i in range(0, chunk_size):
        out.append(await queue.get())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

Then you can implement the timeout using `wait_for`, which will automatically cancel the timed-out coroutine:

```
items = []
try:
    asyncio.wait_for(_get_chunk(queue, size, items))
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    pass
# items now contains the elements _get_chunk managed to extract
# from the queue within the alotted time
```